# Is there some algorithm to match a polygon from a candidate set of polygons?

Tags: geometry, gis, geospatial, computational-geometry

define a set of polygon *A*.
the input is a polygon *B*.

I have to output a set of Polygon *R*, which is the subset of *A*, and if I union all polygon in *R* into a polygon *C*, *C* and *A* should be as similar as possible. Just like figure below:

[image]

Comment: Intersect every candidate polygons with the input and keep those with a significant  overlap. Preferably use a ready-made polygon intersection library, as this is an uneasy problem.

Comment: This depends on what exactly you understand by "similar." Since you want to program this, your computer will need a clear criterion enabling it to say "polygon C is more similar to A than D is." Without that, I'm afraid that your question is too vaguely defined to get a clear answer.